# Real time analytics Kafka Connect to HDFS Hive vs NIFI to Hbase

Tags: hdfs, hbase, apache-nifi, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We have tried kafka connect to push data to HDFS hive tables and NIFI to push data to Hbase from kafka topics but though hbase is nosql db,**Kafka connect HDFS to Hive table seems to be much faster than Nifi and Hbase.**

We are trying to build real time dash boards, Which combination do you feel is the most promising technology stack?

Comment: Too much information missing here... JVM settings between Connect and Nifi? Is Nifi sharing a zookeeper with Kafka? Have you tried a Connect for HBase rather than Hive? https://github.com/Landoop/stream-reactor/tree/master/kafka-connect-hbase

Comment: 1.Both the technology uses same amount of JVM memory 1gb..
2.Yes Nifi is sharing the zookeeper with Kafka
3.kafka connect hbase connectors is not supported by confluent.
Why HDFS can&amp;#39;t be used for real time streaming application sound silly but as Kafka connect performance is much much faster than nifi . why cant we use hdfs for real time dash boards rather than slow nifi hbase combo?

Comment: Why does a connector need to be supported by a vendor? It's open source, so you can patch code yourself, if needed... Landoop should support it... And Nifi is designed for larger records, so only 1G heap is not really recommended for "production workloads". Plus, there are different Kafka processors within Nifi. And Kafka Connect is made and tuned by the same people as core Kafka protocol, so it's safe to assume it's more optimized for those applications